# Append values in dataframe column to string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe

```
    col1        col2
0   1       John Constantine
1   2       ML Engineer
2   3       Colorado
```

I want to append all values in col2 to a list and each row should become a string value in the list. ex

```
output = ['John Constantine', 'ML Engineer' , 'Colorado']
```

The issue is when I use

```
output = df.col2
```

The output becomes a dataframe again. Even when I use `tolist()` I get list of list

Comment: Mind posting the list you got?

Comment: I got the solution. I had to read it as utf-8.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
list(df.col2)
```

Answer (score 1):

`tolist` still work

```
df.col2.tolist()
Out[401]: ['JohnConstantine', 'MLEngineer', 'Colorado']
```

Answer (score 0):

`tolist()` should work:

```
In [14]: df = pandas.DataFrame({
    "col1": [1, 2, 3], 
    "col2": ["John Constantine", "ML Engineer", "Colorado"]
})

In [15]: df.col2.tolist()
Out[15]: ['John Constantine', 'ML Engineer', 'Colorado']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need,

```
df["col2"].tolist()
```